# How turn off curl's verification of the certificate in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, curl, https

If I send `curl -k  "https://abc.com?querystring"`

> -k option to turn off curl's verification of the certificate

How to do this in nodejs If I want to make a GET request?
How to override all http GET request do it in the same way?

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `rejectUnauthorized` [option](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) to `false`.

```
var https = require('https');

var req = https.request({
    hostname: 'example.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET',
    rejectUnauthorized: false
}, function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code:

```
var http = require('http');

var target = {    
    host : 'localhost',
    port : 3000,
    path : 'URL'
    //pfx: Certificate, Private key and CA certificates to use for SSL. Default is null.
    //cert: Public x509 certificate to use. Default null.
};

var Req_options = { 
    host: target.host,
    port: target.port,
    path: target.path,
    agent: false,
    method: 'GET'
};

callback = function(response) {
 var str = ''
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

var req = http.request(Req_options, callback);
req.end();
```

---

**Updated as per comments**:
In the above code, I have changed the `https` & `target` only as follows:

```
var https = require('https'); 

var target = {    
    host : 'www.google.co.in',
    port : 443,
    path : '/'
};
```

The output is as follows:

```
 </html>
    .........
    .........
    .........
    attachEvent&&window.attachEvent("onload",n);google.timers.load.t.prt=e=(new Date).getTime();})();
</script></body></html>
```

For more information, check this [Node.js API docs](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback)

Comment: I get Error: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE